# Which exception should a .NET method throw first if it has a choice?

Tags: .net, exception

I'm wondering what best practices to follow in the case that my .NET method could throw one of two or more exceptions based on the supplied arguments and current object state. Which exception should get precedence and how do I determine that?

An answer for the general case would be best, but here's an example to illustrate my question:

Suppose I have a method which accepts an object parameter. This parameter cannot be null since, say, it has properties or methods which need to be called for the method to do its work. An `ArgumentNullException` could be thrown in this case.

Also suppose my method is on a class, for which its instances first need to be in a specific state for the call to be valid. If they are not, then an `InvalidOperationException` could be thrown here.

Now consider the case where the method is called with a null argument while the class instance is also in an invalid state. Which exception should I throw, `ArgumentNullException` or `InvalidOperationException`? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InvalidOperationException` is my choice for the first exception to be checked for the example described. The processing sequence of this example first requires that the object be in a certain state before it is appropriate to call the method. If it is not in the proper state, then the validation of the method's inputs are irrelevant. So, throwing an `ArugmentNullException` would then mask the real problem of this example.